# Xerox Phaser 6020 won't wake up from sleep

Tags: printer, sleep, network-printer

I recently purchased Xerox Phaser 6020 (it has the latest firmware) it goes to sleep after the default setting time and then most (but not all) times cannot be woken to print at all, or by pressing any of the buttons on the unit. You'd need to hit the power switch and wait for the printer to reboot.
.

It’s my belief that it is not PC related because I have been in contact with Xerox technical guys who I allowed to have access via internet to both my PC’s which they then updated with the latest wireless drivers, but this still did not resolve my problem. On a subsequent call to them they said they had tried all they could and suggested it was a problem with my Windows 10 (one of my PC’s is Win10 64bit and the other Win10 32bit) they said possibly MS were updating my Xerox drivers overnight, so I found how to block MS doing this, but I still have this issue. Has anyone had this problem besides me?

Comment: Hi Richard - can you confirm the firmware version of your Phaser 6020s...? Looking at the release notes for the latest pl2 firmware, one of the enhancement is to resolve the exact issue you mention. The latest fw is available via http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6020/file-download/enus.html?operatingSystem=winxp&fileLanguage=en&contentId=135839&from=downloads&viewArchived=false

Comment: Xerox have now (Nov 31st) supplied me with a new printer and their guys also installed it on my Windows 10 64bit system, however the same issue still ocures. I have updated the firmware on this 6020 also to the latest Ver: .1.06.07.30.3939 - Regards Richard.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do it will not fix the issue. Wire connection is the way to keep your printer without buying a new one. They failed in Wi-Fi aspect and sleep mode in this model.
Still Xerox is excellent brand but not with this one for sure. I have the same issues as well.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have also had another issue for some time; I only print a few pages once a week. The printer often goes into ‘stir tona mode’ (or something) and this uses up a lot of the tona each time, this is so bad I can end up being informed I have an empty tona cassette!  OK so its a good idea to stir the tona every so often but why discard so much tona, or so the tona chip is telling the printer. The answer for me is immediately after it completes printing the last page switch off the printer before it can go into Stir tona mode.